# If $R$ is a ring of integers, $R/I$ is finite

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I am having trouble understanding a line of the proof of the following theorem in Marcus's Number Fields: If $R$ is a ring of integers, then $R/I$ is finite for any nonzero ideal $I$ (this is part of the larger proof that every ring of integers is a Dedekind domain). It goes as follows:

Let $\alpha$ be a nonzero element of $I$ and $m=N^K(\alpha)$ where $K$ is the number field corresponding to $R$. We know $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ and from the definition of norm we see that $m\neq 0$. Moreover $m\in I$: From the definition of norm we have $m=\alpha\beta$ where $\beta$ is a product of conjugates of $\alpha$. These conjugates may not be in $R$, but $\beta$ is because $\beta=m/\alpha$ and it is easy to see that $\beta\in\mathbb{A}$.

My question is: Why is $\beta\in\mathbb{A}$? (note here that $\mathbb{A}$ is the set of all algebraic integers).

Comment: a product of algebraic integers is an algebraic integer

Comment: $\beta$ is a product of conjugates of $\alpha$; these are all algebraic integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\beta$ is a product of conjugates of $\alpha$.

The conjugates of $\alpha$ have the same minimal polynomial as $\alpha$, so they are also algebraic integers.

$\beta$ is thus a product of algebraic integers, which is an algebraic integer.